# Certification Authority Service starts and stops SBS 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, certificate-authority, windows-sbs

We moved from a SBS 2003 Server to a SBS 2008 server relatively recently because the SBS 2003 was having major hardware issues.  I followed the Migration guide to the letter and everything seemed to go smooth.  Until after this last update.  I noticed that AD Certificate service was not started... I started it and it stopped immediately. So I went to Certification Authority MMC and tried to start the service from there and got the following:

> Error 0xxc8000147 (ESE: -327)

So went to the error log and here the associated log:

> Log Name:      Application         Source:
>   Microsoft-Windows-CertificationAuthority
>
> Date:          5/23/2011 7:29:42 AM
>
> Event ID:      17
>
> Task Category: None
>
> Level:         Error
>
> Keywords:      Classic
>
> User:          SYSTEM
>
> Computer:      *********.**********.lan
>
> Description: Active Directory Certificate Services did not start:
>   Unable to initialize the database connection for
>   **********-*********-CA.  Error 0xc8000147 (ESE: -327).

Event Xml:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-CertificationAuthority" 
        Guid="{6A71D062-9AFE-4F35-AD08-52134F85DFB9}" 
        EventSourceName="CertSvc" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="49754">17</EventID> 
    <Version>0</Version> 
    <Level>2</Level> 
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-05-23T14:29:42.000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>1513838</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />

    <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" />
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>******.**********.lan</Computer>
    <Security UserID="*****" />   
  </System>   
  <EventData Name="MSG_E_DB_INIT_FAILED">
    <Data Name="CACommonName">*********-*********-CA</Data>
    <Data Name="ErrorCode">Error 0xc8000147 (ESE: -327)</Data>   
  </EventData> 
</Event>
```

I have been searching for solutions to this issue and really haven't found anything related to the error code for CA services.

Comment: try running the command "dcdiag" on the new server to see if it leads you in a better direction of getting a usable error message. I think that Microsoft offers free migration customer support.

Comment: running dcdiag it passed all tests

Answer (score 1):

I recommend removing and reinstalling the Certificate Authority role.  This is expressly supported by MS and they even provide an SBS2008 HOWTO [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd421659%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

eseutil worked for me after I accidently deleted everything in CertLog rather than just the log files.

With the AD Certificate service still stopped, I copied back the edb and jrs files, then ran eseutil /p on the edb (note without the logs) and it repaired the database.

I then started AD Certificate services without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

esentutl /p - repairs the database. 
It will warn your that any transaction log data will be lost.

I did not have a choice, and this was the only function that worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

```
cd \windows\system32\certlog

esentutl /p "sbs2008-ca.edb"

dsa.msc
dssite.msc
dcdiag

repadmin /syncall
```

Comment: To make this a useful answer, please add an explanation what this does and how it helps to solve the OPs problem.